# Optimize MYSQL query TIMEDIFF in Select and where Clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, alias

I have the following  query which runs over a large database.

```
select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkStartTime,walkEndTime)) 
from users 
where categoryType='1' 
and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkStartTime,walkEndTime)) < 1000
```

If you notice the TIME_TO_SEC is used in the query as well as in the where clause.

I tried for alias but, as alias can't be use so, don't know what could be a better solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find only one optimized way to query your problem. When you calculate a value from your fields in the WHERE clause MySQL must calculate each row. So it is every time a full table scan and it can use much time and is not very performant.

Spend a new field with the calculated timediff and a index. you not must calculated it, you can use a **VIRTUAL PERSISTENT** field which calculated it automatic when you insert or change a field

I have made same Samples to clarify my idea:

**First create a new table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `walkStartTime` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `walkEndTime` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryType` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diffp` INT(11) AS (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkEndTime,walkStartTime))) PERSISTENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `diffs` (`diffp`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Insert some stuff:**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `walkStartTime`, `walkEndTime`, `categoryType`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-09-27 07:00:00', '2015-09-27 07:30:00', 1),
    (2, '2015-09-27 07:00:01', '2015-09-27 07:31:00', 1),
    (3, '2015-09-27 07:00:02', '2015-09-27 07:32:00', 0),
    (4, '2015-09-27 07:00:10', '2015-09-27 07:15:00', 1),
    (5, '2015-09-27 07:00:20', '2015-09-27 07:16:10', 1),
    (6, '2015-09-27 07:00:30', '2015-09-27 07:17:20', 0),
    (7, '2015-09-27 07:01:00', '2015-09-27 07:10:00', 1),
    (8, '2015-09-27 07:02:00', '2015-09-27 07:09:33', 1),
    (9, '2015-09-27 07:03:00', '2015-09-27 08:12:00', 1);
```

**try your query and EXPLAIN it: see that they read all 9 rows**

```
MariaDB [tmp]> select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkEndTime,walkStartTime))
    -> from users
    -> where categoryType='1'
    -> and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkEndTime,walkStartTime)) < 1000;
+--------------------------------------------------+
| TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkEndTime,walkStartTime)) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                              890 |
|                                              950 |
|                                              540 |
|                                              453 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> EXPLAIN select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkEndTime,walkStartTime))
    -> from users
    -> where categoryType='1'
    -> and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkEndTime,walkStartTime)) < 1000;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    9 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
```

**run my optimized query with the new VIRTUAL field (diffp):**

```
MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT diffp
    -> FROM users
    -> WHERE diffp < 1000;
+-------+
| diffp |
+-------+
|   453 |
|   540 |
|   890 |
|   950 |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> EXPLAIN SELECT diffp
    -> FROM users
    -> WHERE diffp < 1000;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | users | range | diffs         | diffs | 5       | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
```

so you can see MySQL only reads 3 ROWS and use the Index.
It is also possible that can can more speedup when you using a composite index over both fields (diffp and CategoryType) and the order of the both fields in the index can also change the speed.

Comment: nice explanation. But one question though, Keys as "diffs" how would be helpful?

Comment: When you call a function in the WHERE clause with fields as argument MySQL must call this function for every ROW the see if the ROW to use for this query and also MySQL cant store the RESULT in the query cache because the result from the function can every time different.

Diffs is only a VIRTUAL field where MySQL automatic stores the difference in seconds  between the two timestamps. If you also put a KEY on this field MySQL can directly search values over it in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkStartTime,walkEndTime)) diff FROM users WHERE categoryType=1
) a
WHERE a.diff < 1000
```

### Update

assuming you have a column named user_id which contains the user's id

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(diff) as 'avg_diff', MAX(diff) as 'max_diff' FROM (
    SELECT user_id, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(walkStartTime,walkEndTime)) diff FROM users WHERE categoryType=1
) a
WHERE a.diff < 1000
GROUP BY 1
```

This will return each user's id, average diff and max diff

Comment: Can you suggest something on getting both MAX and AVG time , like AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF())) and MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF()))?

Comment: @andyPaul, average is usually user wise or something else. Can you please share some sample data and your expected output?